# Unplugged Mobile Controls: Loading Button don´t work

Tags: xpages, lotus, teamstudio-unplugged

when using the unplugged mobile controls, in a view 20 entries were loaded in the Unp|FlatViewList Xpage (by default).
When i click on the "load more" button (or when I change the settings to "pull" instead of the button), no further entries were loaded, and no error occurs. I have this problem with the Browser (Firefox/Chrome) and with the iPhone.

Do you have any solutions for this issue?

Regards

Stefan

Comment: Are you using the unpFlatView control (http://unplugged.github.io/unplugged-controls/320/UnpFlatView.html) and have you added all required resources to your nsf (unpHeader and UnpFlatViewList)?

Comment: Yes, i´m using the unpFlatView control and i have added all the resources. To be sure, i´ve updated all the resources. Now, the "load" button works only one time, and after the the load, the button disappears.

Edit: Problem solved, the Footer was hiding the Button

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Does this help from the documentation?

> The "Load More" function requires the presence of the XPage called UnpFlatViewList, it is this which is used by the control to perform Ajax requests to get each chunk of data to display to the user.

From this page http://unplugged.github.io/unplugged-controls/320/UnpFlatView.html

If not can you provide the XML from the XPage or Custom Control?

Please let me know if I can be of any further assistance.